# How do you send a URL request with upper-case characters in the domain name?

Tags: domains, url, testing, case-sensitive

I wanted to see how my site would respond to a request if the hostname is in capital letters instead of the usual lower-case. I tried doing that on FireFox and Chrome, but they automatically convert the hostname to lower-case letters. Then I tried using `wget` on terminal, but it too convert the request to lower-case. Is there any way I can test this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `--header` option of wget.

```
wget --header 'Host: EXAMPLE.COM' http://example.com
```

with `--debug` you could see actual request

```
wget --debug --header 'Host: EXAMPLE.COM' http://example.com

...

---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: EXAMPLE.COM
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
...
```

But actually it's useless unless you use some custom web server. All modern web servers take care of converting hostname to lowercase.

Comment: "All modern web servers take care of converting hostname to lowercase." - Web servers (Apache at least) don't actually "convert" the hostname to lowercase. The web server compares the `Host` header case-insensitively when mapping the request to the server/vHost, however, the `Host` header is passed through as-is to other server-side scripts (including Apache config) where it will be compared case-sensitively, unless you take steps not to. However, all modern "browsers" do convert the hostname to lowercase before making the request (but bots might not).